# Range Sum Query Question about Javascript Prototypes (Leetcode)

Tags: javascript, oop, caching

I am having trouble figuring out why certain solutions to this problem below have faster executions than others. I think it has to do with the prototype keyword, but I cannot grasp why immediately.

Link to the problem statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-query-immutable/

I have solved this problem the following way:

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 */
var NumArray = function(nums) {
        this.nums = nums;

};

/** 
 * @param {number} i 
 * @param {number} j
 * @return {number}
 */
NumArray.prototype.sumRange = function(i, j) {
            var sum = 0 ;
            for(; i <= j; i++){
                sum += this.nums[i];
            }
            return sum;
    };

/** 
 * Your NumArray object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * var obj = new NumArray(nums)
 * var param_1 = obj.sumRange(i,j)
 */
```

However, after looking at the discussion section, this answer yields a faster result:

```
function NumArray(nums) {
  this.sums = [];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += nums[i];
    this.sums.push(sum);
  }
}

/** 
 * @param {number} i 
 * @param {number} j
 * @return {number}
 */


NumArray.prototype.sumRange = function(i, j) {
  return this.sums[j] - (i > 0 ? this.sums[i - 1] : 0);
};
```

My answer results in around 21st percentile, while the second answer results in around 95th percentile. I am confused about why it is faster.

The problem notes that there are many successive calls to the sumRange function after the instantiation of the NumArray object. I don't see why more calls slows down my code in comparison. I read in the solution that it may be related to caching, but I am unsure exactly how such caching is achieved in the context of these solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: the 2nd one does some work on instantiation, the first one does it every time. if you change the array after creation, the 2nd one won't work anymore.

Comment: try `this.slice(s,s+len).reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version has to loop every time you call `sumRange()`, so it's O(n). But creating a `NumArray` object is O(1).

The second version only loops once, when you create the `NumArray` object, so creation is O(n). But its version of `sumRange()` takes advantage of the associative property of addition and an algebraic transformation:

```
(nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2] + nums[3]) == (nums[0] + nums[1]) + (nums[2] + nums[3])
```

therefore

```
(nums[2] + nums[3]) == (nums[0] + nums[1] + nums[2] + nums[3]) - (nums[0] + nums[1])
```

Since `sums[i]` is the total of `nums[0] + ... nums[i]`, you can calculate the sum of any sub-array using that difference. So it doesn't have to loop, it's O(1).

The higher cost of creating a `NumArray` is amortized over all the times you call `sumRange()`.